# Wifi disconnects after connecting a bluetooth device on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, wireless, bluetooth

I am using Windows 8.1 along with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Lenovo G50-70. Whenever I connect my JBL Bluetooth (v4.2) earphone, my laptop's WiFi disconnects after a few minutes. Everything works fine when I am running windows. So this is an issue with Ubuntu. Please, someone, help me with this issue.

I tried this command:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=1 power_save=0 auto_agg=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf > /dev/null
```

but this did not help.
I executed `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` to get my hardware info, and here is the output:

> 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
>   RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
>   Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b736]
>
> Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be Kernel modules: rtl8723be
>   03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230] [1002:666f] (rev ff)`